# Can Windows ocr recognize custom symbols/font?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-phone, win-universal-app, ocr

I'm developing for UWP, Windows has an OCR engine: Windows.Media.Ocr

My question is: someone knows if the Windows OCR can be trained to recognize new characters or use a custom font? if yes, how i can do this?

what i want to achieve is to recognize non alphabetical symbols. I want to recognize per example the character ⌰ (unicode: U+2330) or ⌖ (U+2316).

The characters that i want to recognize are symbols not for any language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used `Windows.Media.Ocr` library in my [WUP application](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/optical-character-recognizer/9nblggh3v84v) and here some test result with different font

---

### Arial

**Font** - Arial
**Test Words** - Hello @ World
**Expected Result** - Hello @ World
**Original Result** - Hello @ World
**Accuracy** - 100%

[image]

---

### Agency FB

**Font** - Agency FB
**Test Words** - Hello @ World
**Expected Result** - Hello @ World
**Original Result** - Hello World
**Accuracy** - 84.6% (Missed - @ symbol and one space)

[image]

---

### Modern

**Font** - Modern
**Test Words** - Hello @ World
**Expected Result** - Hello @ World
**Original Result** - Hello @ world
**Accuracy** - 92.3% (W recognised as w)

[image]

---

### Lucida Handwriting

**Font** - Lucida Handwriting
**Test Words** - Hello @ World
**Expected Result** - Hello @ World
**Original Result** - HeUe@ worw
**Accuracy** - 46.1%
[image]

---

## Update [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35850340/can-windows-ocr-recognize-custom-symbols-font/35859532?noredirect=1#comment59388198_35859532)]

### Arial Unicode MS

**Font** - Arial Unicode MS
**Test Symbols** - ⌰ ⌖
**Expected Result** - ⌰ ⌖
**Original Result** - (Unable to Recognize)
**Accuracy** - 0%

[image]

---

## Update 2

### [image]

Hope this helpful to you.

Comment: I think that you didn't exactly answer my question. But you give me ideas and lead me to other possible ways to solve my problem. Thanks. 

So, what i want to achieve is to recognize non alphabetical symbols. I want to recognize per example the character ⌰ (unicode: U+2330) or ⌖ (U+2316).

Can you please tell me if in your example with Windows OCR you are able to recognize this Miscellaneous Technical Unicode subset characters. I will try it  tomorrow. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Xaren please check the Update 1 section of my answer. Hope this helpful to you

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you suggest to me a way to recognize special characters

Comment: Special Characters like ⌰ & ⌖ OR @,#,%,^ etc??

Comment: Characters like ⌰ & ⌖

Comment: in addition to this, windows media OCR is useless once you want to detect the user scribbled notes. I'd really like to see an example on how to recognize the user entered text (via touch) with some acceptable success rate. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35954842/windows-ocr-engine-fails-to-recognize-the-text-in-canvas-converted-to-bitmap/35964300#35964300

Comment: Hey @Vineet Choudhary , what about the following font........ ict4u.net/databases/database-images/… could i recognize the following font. or can you take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824278/add-new-language-for-ocr-engine

Comment: @CloyMonis please check update 2, there is currently no way to train the OCR library with custom data set

Answer (score 2):

I think a short answer to your question is no. As it is said in [Supported languages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.ocr.aspx#supported_languages) sections in [Windows.Media.Ocr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.ocr.aspx) namespace:

> There are 25 supported languages. Based on recognition accuracy and performance, supported languages are divided into three groups:
>
> - **Excellent:** Czech, Danish, Dutch, English, Finnish, French, German, Hungarian, Italian, Norwegian, Polish, Portuguese, Romanian, Serbian Cyrillic, Serbian Latin, Slovak, Spanish and Swedish.
> - **Very good:** Chinese Simplified, Greek, Japanese, Russian and Turkish.
> - **Good:** Chinese Traditional and Korean.
>
> The language is required information for correct text recognition. Every language uses some language-specific resources, so it must be specified in advance.
>
> **Note**  Only languages installed on the device can be used. A user can install new languages through the **Settings** app.

So if your symbols are not for any language, the OCR engine won't recognize it.

And for custom font, As Vineet Choudhary's answer shows, maybe the OCR engine can recognize some, the accuracy of text recognition depends on your font. If it's handwritten or cursive text, the accuracy of text recognition may be very low.

Comment: Hey @Jay Zuo - MSFT , what about the following font........ http://www.ict4u.net/databases/database-images/micr.jpg.................How could i recognize the following font.